# White lines instead of words in CompletionWindow (CodeCompletion namespace) when AvalonEdit used from F#

Tags: c#, f#, code-completion, avalonedit

I am using the AvalonEdit C# library from F# code and doing code completion. Everything seems to work as expected, the code completion window is shown, the tooltips at its individual lines pop-up correctly, the selected words are inserted into the document. The only problem is that all lines in the completion window are blank, as if they contained nothing.

Stepping through the code in the Visual Studion 2013 is not perfectly usable here, because it has unexpected impact on the behaviour of the completion window, which is different from when breakpoints are not used.

Here is the MyCompletionData taken from the AvalonEdit Help and rewritten into F# :

```ml
module CompletionData

open ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.CodeCompletion
open System
open System.Windows.Media.Imaging

/// Implements AvalonEdit ICompletionData interface to provide the entries in the
/// completion drop down.
type MyCompletionData (text:string) = 
    let _text = text

    interface ICompletionData with

        member this.Complete (textArea, completionSegment, insertionRequestEventArgs) =
            textArea.Document.Replace(completionSegment, ((this :> ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text: string));

        // Use this property if you want to show a fancy UIElement in the list.
        member this.Content
            with get () = (this :> ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text :> obj

         member this.Description
            with get () = ("Description for " + (this :> ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text ) :> obj

        member  this.Image
            with get () = null 

        member this.Priority
            with get () = 1.0

        member this.Text = _text
```

Comment: I have not the privilege to include pictures here. Some images related to the issue and the complete code is here [https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/issues/28](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/issues/28) .

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476046/databinding-a-f-viewmodel

> The most direct workaround is to define it as an explicit property
>   (and the interface implementation can just refer to the main property

```ml
type MyCompletionData (text:string) = 
    let _text = text

    member this.Text = text

    member this.Complete (textArea:TextArea, completionSegment, insertionRequestEventArgs) =
            textArea.Document.Replace(completionSegment, ((this :> ICSharpCode..CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text: string));

    member this.Content = (this :> ICSharpCode..CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text :> obj

    member this.Description = ("Description for " + (this :> ICSharpCode..CodeCompletion.ICompletionData).Text ) :> obj

    member  this.Image = null

    member this.Priority = 1.0

    interface ICompletionData with

        member this.Complete (textArea, completionSegment, insertionRequestEventArgs) =
            this.Complete (textArea, completionSegment, insertionRequestEventArgs)

        // Use this property if you want to show a fancy UIElement in the list.
        member this.Content = this.Content

        member this.Description = this.Description

        member  this.Image = this.Image

        member this.Priority = this.Priority            

        member this.Text = this.Text
```